# I can't enable MFA for Oracle Identity Cloud Service user

Tags: multi-factor-authentication, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I just sign-up an account of [Oracle Cloud](https://cloud.oracle.com/)

After I logged in, It seem the system automatically created a tenancy for me and added me to an Identity Providers named `oracleidentitycloudservice`.

They also create one more user starts with `oracleidentitycloudservice/username`.
This is identity user page, both 2 of them is me. One of them is federated with `oracleidentitycloudservice` which is created automatically.
[image]

I can enable MFA for the second account.
But I can not enable MFA account for `oracleidentitycloudservice/username`:
[image]

When I want to login to Identity Console page, I need to use this SSO method:
[image]

It seem risky if Identity Console page doesn't provide MFA feature. That's what I worry about.

Question is:

1. Is it safe if I delete `oracleidentitycloudservice/username`?
2. How can I enable MFA for `oracleidentitycloudservice/username` from Oracle Infastructure page?
3. If Oracle is providing a complicated way to enable MFA for `oracleidentitycloudservice/username`, could it be a security issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For those who are in the same situation, here is step to Enable MFA for Oracle Identity cloud service user:

1. Sign in by this SSO method at this screen:
   [image]
2. Go to `Service User Console` on top-right screen
   [image: List item]
3. Go to Admin Console of Identity
   [image]
4. Go to My profile on top-right screen
   [image]
5. Go to Security tab, our goal is to give the account permissions so that `MFA` item shows on this screen. At this moment MFA is not yet enabled, move to next step
   [image]
6. Go to Admin console at top-right screen
   [image]
7. Go to Security -> MFA at left side panel, check the box `Mobile App Passcode`
   [image]
8. Go to Security -> Sign-On Policies, edit the Default Policy
   [image]
9. Edit Default Sign-on Rule
   [image]
10. Select the option that you prefer. It's upto you.
    [image]
11. Go to Security tab and here you can enable `MFA` for your IDCS account
    [image]
12. Sign-out and Sign-in again. Now you can use MFA to login.
    [image]

Comment: On my side, I cannot see the 2-step Verification. Is it exlusive to EE license only?

Comment: @刘宇翔 No, I enabled it when my account still in free-tier account. Can you explain what step you are stuck in?

Comment: I mean in Step 5, I can only see Email as Recovery options but no `2-step verification` section there.

Comment: @刘宇翔 It's weird, maybe you should try these steps to enable MFA for your OCI account first:   
1. Sign On to "Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Direct Sigin In" section

2.  Go to `User Setting`

3. Click to tab "Enable Multi Factor Authentication"

Comment: Step 5 is showing what it looks like when MFA is available, but you will not see it until later in the process. After step 10, you need to go back to the screen in Step 5 and enable MFA (this is where you see the barcode for Oracle MFA app, or a different MFA app). Then logout and login and you'll see the prompt from the final Step. Edit: I have edited the answer to clarify the flow. Worked for me!

Comment: Unfortunately this one is outdated already, I've updated @daniel-fernández answer with actual screenshots as his answer seems to be correct currently.

Comment: There is no Service User Console in the Cloud Console drop-down now. You need to go to Identity -> Federation -> Oracle Identity Cloud Service Console. @daniel-fernández's answer only works if you don't use SSO (they probably migrated everyone though). With SSO that only tells you 'Multi-factor authentication can only be enabled by the user' in the end.

Comment: And is there no regular OTP option? And my Duo and FIDO are also greyed out. Paid features?

Comment: @FrederickZhang "And my Duo and FIDO are also greyed out. Paid features?" - [Probably, yes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/identity-cloud/uaids/oracle-identity-cloud-service-pricing-models.html)

Comment: @DmitryVerhoturov I've [added an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75348332/1768141) that's current and works for Free Tier accounts.

Answer (score 9):

Here's how you enable MFA (TOTP Authenticator) for Free Tier accounts:

1. Navigate to https://www.oracle.com/in/cloud/sign-in.html
2. Enter your **Cloud Account Name** and click **Next**
   [image: OCI Login - 1]
3. Select **oracleidentitycloudservice** as your Identity Provider and click **Continue**
   [image: OCI Login - 2]
4. Enter your username and password
   [image: OCI Login - 3]
5. Click on hamburger menu and select [Identity & Security > Federation](https://cloud.oracle.com/identity/federations)
   [image: OCI Login - 4]
6. Click on **OracleIdentityCloudService**
   [image: OCI Login - 5]
7. Click on the link next to **Oracle Identity Cloud Service Console**
   [image: OCI Login - 6]
8. You should be logged into the Oracle Identity Cloud Service console. Click on the hamburger menu and select **Security > MFA**
   [image: OCI Login - 7]
9. I don't see a way to enable **Duo Security** or **FIDO Authenticator** at this screen. Probably because the license type is [**Foundation**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/identity-cloud/uaids/oracle-identity-cloud-service-pricing-models.html) but if you found a way to enable either of those, please edit this answer. If not, enable **Mobile App Passcode** and **Mobile App Notification** and click **Save**
   [image: OCI Login - 8]
10. Click on the top right corner of the screen with your initials and select **My Profile**
    [image: OCI Login - 9]
11. Click on the **Security** tab and you should see a **2-Step Verification** section with an **Enable** button.

[image: OCI Login - 10]

12. Click on **Enable** and select **Mobile App**
    [image: OCI Login - 11]
13. Check **Offline Mode or Use Another Autenticator App**
    [image: OCI Login - 12]
14. Scan the QR code with your favorite TOTP app (I used Authy) and enter a code and click **Verify**
15. You'll now have a 2SV factor enabled
    [image: OCI Login - 13]
16. Go back to the console by clicking on your initials at the top right corner and selecting **Admin Console**

[image: OCI Login - 14]

17. Click on the hamburger menu and navigate to **Security > Sign-On Policies**
    [image: OCI Login - 15]
18. Edit the **Default Sign-On Policy** by clicking on [image: edit icon] and selecting **Edit**
    [image: OCI Login - 16]
19. Click on the **Sign-On Rules** tab and edit the **Default Sign-On Rule** by clicking on [image: edit icon] and selecting **Edit**
    [image: OCI Login - 17]
20. Scroll down to **Actions** section and enable **Prompt for an additional factor** and leave the rest at defaults and click **Save**
    [image: OCI Login - 18]
21. Log out and log back in again (alternatively open the **Oracle Identity Cloud Service Console** URL from step 7 in a private/incognito tab) and verify that you're prompted for the TOTP code after entering your username and password.
    [image: OCI Login - 19]

Comment: You're my hero. I thought I'll never solve this. Oracle's letter with a prompt to enable MFA looked like a joke, given how obscure the process is and that documentation completely ignores the fact that there are multiple consoles with the same "Security" section in them.

Comment: I too wouldn't have figured it out either if it weren't for @hoangmnsd's orginal answer and Frederick Zhang's comment about where to find the link to Oracle Identity Cloud Service console. I agree that requiring 21 steps to enable MFA is way too obscure and will probably lead to most people not bothering to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
I was following an official training from Oracle and found that the option did not appear because I was using the federated user.

You may manage all the users from the the lines button at the top-left corner and from there 'Identity & Security'.
[First menu Identity & Security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNLgW.png)

Once you click on that option, you will see:
[Choose Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH7Lr.png)

And this is the main user's options with the MFA and password reset if required:
[User's options including MFA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Qjlj.png)
Dani.

Answer (score 0):

This is already old information, OCI is constantly changing it's dashboard. If you can't find the correct screens anymore, see this Oracle Documentation page, with which I set the policy after I enabled 2FA on my profile via Security:
https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Identity/mfa/understand-multi-factor-authentication.htm?Highlight=mfa
After that 2FA is asked after you login with your credentials.