# Adding MFA on OCI gives "can only be enabled by the user" error

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have a similar setup as described in the question [I can't enable MFA for Oracle Identity Cloud Service user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68097557/5362795) but a different problem: I cannot enable Multi-Factor Authentication for **any** user.

On the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure (OCI) console, I do see the "Enable Multi-Factor Authentication" in one of the accounts under *Identity >> Users >> User Details*. After following all the steps, including scanning the barcode and entering the verification code, when I click the *verify* button on OCI I get this error: "*Multi-factor authentication can only be enabled by the user.*"

What does this mean? I thought I was the user! I've searched online for this error and looked at [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Identity/Tasks/usingmfa.htm), but see no clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to enable 2FA! It's a convoluted process, so it's no wonder I was not able to do it before. In a nutshell, the administrator needs to configure the end user account to use MFA, and only after that, the user will be able to "enroll" to use MFA. In my case, the administrator and the end user are the same account.

First, I went to *Identity & Security > Identity > Federation* and then clicked on *OracleIdentityCloudService* which opens another page. Then clicked on the link shown after *Oracle Identity Cloud Service Console* which opens up a different administration web console.

There are too many steps to explain here, but on this new console I essentially did the following:

1. Enabled Mobile App Passcode (under *Security > MFA*)
2. Added a new group for MFA (*Groups > Add*) and included my own user
3. Added and dragged to the top, a new sign-on policy (*Security > Sign-on Policies*) to "Prompt for an additional factor" with the condition "And is a member of these groups" (using the group I just created)
4. Signed out and signed in again
5. After login, I followed the prompt (screenshot below) and added verification with another authentication app

[image]

And this time it worked! These steps and screenshots are shown nicely in a [medium post](https://learnoci.cloud/how-to-enable-mfa-in-oci-81c2d63de52f), which has different guides for three "different Oracle products". The steps outlined above are for IDCS. The error shown in my original question comes from trying the method for "Old OCI IAM", which might have worked if steps 1 - 3 above had been completed beforehand, but I didn't test it, since I followed the prompt given at login instead.

I also found an [Oracle article](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/infographics/idcs_enabling_and_configuring_mfa/index.html) that shows some of the steps above, with screenshots as well. Hope this helps people better secure their accounts.

Answer (score 1):

This videos explains how to setup MFA for oracle cloud.

There are three ways to login and setup MFA for oracle cloud:

1. Direct Sign-in
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSDBlzGYYjo&t=43s
2. IDCS accounts
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSDBlzGYYjo&t=136s
3. Identity Domains
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSDBlzGYYjo&t=299s

With this explanation I was finally able to activate 2FA.

Comment: Please avoid writing link-only answers. If the link dies your answer will no longer make sense. Include all relevant information in your answer and provide the links as references.

Answer (score 0):

MFA can only be enabled for `Your Own Account`.

Tenancy `Administrators` have no way to enable MFA for other users in OCI but `Administrators` can disable MFA for other users.

`Your Own Account` meaning the one which you used for login.

For ex: In below snapshot from OCI, I am trying to enable MFA for other user. I am the `Administrator` for this tenancy.

[image: OCI MFA Error]

Comment: Thanks, upvoted for the explanation and the picture which shows what I see exactly. But I want to enable MFA for my own account/user, and I can't find a way to do it. I only see two users on the console, one created automatically. There's only one with the MFA option and I when I try to enable it, I get the above error. So I guess the question is, how do I access my own user/account... I'm the only one using it.

Comment: @Nagev: Please check the documentation for MFA related to [Identity Domains](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Identity/mfa/manage-2-step-verification.htm)

Alternatively you can also try to check the users created and reset the password of your own user and try to login using the new password and then try to setup MFA (Menu to reset password: `Identity & Security --> Identity --> Domains --> Users`

Comment: The password reset was valid one time only, it didn't prompt me for a new password. And I still get the same error when trying to enable MFA. The documentation does not address this issue. Thanks anyway.